# Java: Checking for duplicate values in one array and assigning a simpler ID into another array of the same size

Tags: java, arrays

I have two arrays:

array 1:

```
 {101,101,101,102,102,103,103,104,104,105}
```

and array 2:

```
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

For every duplicate element in array 1, I want an new ID in each element of array 2. This the result I am trying to achieve:

```
array1 = {101,101,101,102,102,103,103,104,104,105};
array2 = {1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5};
```

You might get a better idea of what I am trying to do when you see my code.

The code I have provided is the closest I have gotten to getting the result I want. I have tried switching up the logic in many different ways and haven't gotten a result better than what the code I have provided gives.

```
public class Challenge {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int[] arr1 = {11,11,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,15};
        int[] arr2 = new int[10];

        System.out.println("Initial arrays");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2));

        int id = 1;
        int count = 0;
        int trueCount = 0;
        boolean isMatching = true;
        boolean beginWrite = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr1.length; j++) {
                count++;
                    if (arr1[i] != arr1[j]) {
                        isMatching = false;
                        trueCount = count;
                        count = 0;
                    for (int k = 0; k < arr1.length; k++) {
                        if (k == trueCount) {
                            beginWrite = false;
                        }
                        if (beginWrite == true) {
                            arr2[i] = id;
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Result");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2));

    }
}
```

Output:

Initial arrays

```
[11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Result

```
[11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Expected output:

Initial arrays

```
[11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Result

```
[11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your question and one thing that could make your life a lot easier is a data structure called a `HashMap`.

If you're unfamiliar it is basically a set of (key, value) pairs where each key is unique making it so we could put your unaltered ids as keys and new ids as values. Then as we're iterating, we can check to see if we've created an id for that unaltered id yet and if we have use that id.

The code with this added to it would look something like this:

```
public class Challenge {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int[] arr1 = {11,11,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,15};
        int[] arr2 = new int[10];
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> ids = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        System.out.println("Initial arrays");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2));

        int id = 1;
        int count = 0;
        int trueCount = 0;
        boolean isMatching = true;
        boolean beginWrite = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            if (ids.containsKey(arr1[i])) {
                arr2[i] = ids.get(arr1[i]);
            } else {
                ids.put(arr1[i], id);
                arr2[i] = id;
                id++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Result");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The old fashion way with a single **for** loop:

```
int[] array1 = {104,105,101,103,102,103,102,101,104,101};
int[] array2 = new int[array1.length];

System.out.println("Original Array: " + Arrays.toString(array1).replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", ""));
Arrays.sort(array1);  // Make sure the Array is sorted (in the case it isn't).
System.out.println("Array: Sorted:  " + Arrays.toString(array1).replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", ""));

int prevValue = array1[0];
array2[0] = 1;
int counter = 1;

for (int i = 1; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (array1[i] == prevValue) {
        array2[i] = counter;
        prevValue = array1[i];
    }
    else {
        counter++;
        array2[i] = counter;
        prevValue = array1[i];
    }
} 
System.out.println("The Result:     " + Arrays.toString(array2).replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Initialize the first value of `arr2` to the id = 1
2. If the next value of arr1 is the same as the previous, keep setting same id
3. If the next value of arr1 is not the same as the previous, increment id by 1

   ```
   int[] arr1 = {11,11,11,12,12,13,14,14,14,15};
   int[] arr2 = new int[10];

   ...

   int id = 1;
   for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
       if (i == 0) {
           arr2[i] = id;
       } else {
           if ((arr1[i])==(arr1[i-1])) {
               arr2[i] = id;
           } else {
               id++;
               arr2[i] = id;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

> ```
> Initial arrays
>
> [11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15]
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>
> Result
>
> [11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15]
> [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
int[] arr1 = {11,11,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,15};
int[] arr2 = new int[arr1.length];

System.out.println("Initial arrays");
System.out.println();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2));

int[] id = {1};
Map<Integer, Integer> ids = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++)
    arr2[i] = ids.compute(arr1[i], (k, v) -> v == null ? id[0]++ : v);

System.out.println();
System.out.println("Result");
System.out.println();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2));
```